# PhantomJS font not render for some text

Tags: phantomjs

Partial Text is not rendering correct on a site.

From browser:
[image]

From phantomjs:
[image]

Machine :Fedora 64 bit

Phantomjs version : 1.9.7

Dependencies already installed :

- yum install urw-fonts
- sudo yum install fontconfig freetype libfreetype.so.6 libfontconfig.so.1 libstdc++.so.6

On another Windows platform works fine, only issues with Linux environment. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with phantomjs and rendering of fonts for special characters (Japanese, Chinese, Hindi, etc.), and that's how I solved the problem:

1. Download the corresponding `.ttf` [Unicode fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) file. There are several free sites on the web, but you have several Unicode fonts free files for several different character maps [here](http://www.fonts2u.com/category.html?id=92).
2. Save the `.ttf` files in your server/machine either in the directory `/etc/fonts` or in the directory `~/.fonts`. The latter is also a unix directory, if it does not exist, create it, and you need it if you have no root privileges (shared server for example)
3. Run either `fc-cache -fv /etc/fonts` or `fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts/` accordingly. This [fc-cache](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-cache) command scans the font directories on the system and builds font information cache files

Then in the phantomjs code, use always `utf-8` either for **file system**

```
var HTMLfile = fs.open(path + file_name, {
    mode: 'r', //read
    charset: 'utf-8' 
});
var content = HTMLfile.read();
HTMLfile.close();
```

or for **webpage**

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var settings = {
  operation: "POST",
  encoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    some: "data",
    another: ["custom", "data"]
  })
};
```

After long search, it worked for me.